# getting elements in a list according to list of indices in python

Tags: python

I have a list of indices, something like:

```
b=[0,2]
```

and a list of elements:

```
a = ['elem0','elem1','elem2']
```

I need a list that is composed of the elements in `a` with the indices in `b`
(in this example: `['elem0','elem2']`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[a[i] for i in b]
```

Answer (score 1):

Or:

```
from operator import itemgetter

b=[0,2]
a = ['elem0','elem1','elem2']

print itemgetter(*b)(a)
>>> ('elem0','elem2')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension to map the indexes to the list:

```
b=[0,2]
a = ['elem0','elem1','elem2'] 

sublist = [a[i] for i in b]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>ipython
In [1]: b=[0,2]
In [2]: a = ['elem0','elem1','elem2']
In [3]: [a[i] for i in b]
Out[3]: ['elem0', 'elem2']
```

Look up "list comprehensions" in the python manual if you don't know them.